# question about dsmod group 

Tags: active-directory

i am trying to assign user A with the same group memberships as user B. the problem is user A is already member of some of the groups user B is and when i try to run below command it errors out as soon as it finds the group user A is already member of. e.g. user A is member of abc, def and user B is member of abc, ghi, lmn and when i run this command, it stops processing and gives me an error saying user A is already member of group abc and doesnt go any further.

so could you please tell me how can make the assignment keep going and skip whatever group user A is assigned to?

> dsquery user -samid B | dsget user -memberof -expand |dsmod group -addmbr "A"

please provide non-programming solution as not good at programming.

thank you...

Answer (score 2):

Use the `-c` parameter.  As in:

`dsquery user -samid B | dsget user -memberof -expand |dsmod group -c -addmbr "A"`

Comment: is it possible you can tell me a good website or book which i can use to learn VBScript to get the reports from AD or do user administation in AD or export AD results into excel, etc. any help would be nice!!!

Comment: quite frankly the ds* command are quite good at doing the above listed requirements.